# .plistから読み込んだ文字列が\nで改行されない

Tags: swift, xcode

プロパティリストから読み込んだ文字列を改行してUILabelに表示したいのですが、
「1行目\n2行目」という形で
\nがそのまま表示されて改行されません。

プロパティリストには画像のように入力しています。

```
func loadTitles() {
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DefaultValues", ofType: "plist")

            let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)! as! [NSDictionary]

            for i in 0..<array.count {
                let item = array[i]
                let title = item["title"] as! String
                let label = UILabel()
                label.text = title//「1行目\n2行目」と表示される
                //1行目
                //2行目
                //と表示したい
            }
        }
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡単で済みませんが、`\n`は文字列ですので今の結果は当然の結果になります。
改行を含むValueを持つプロパティリストを作成するには、

1行目`Option+Return`
2行目

の様に打ち込んで下さい。これで、plist editor上では1行目しか見えませんが、`Option+Return`を打ち込んだ回数分＋１の行を含むStringがValueに設定できます。

蛇足ですが、`Option+Return`はオプションキーを押しながらリターンキーのタイプです。

Comment: すこいです！できました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: `option+return`は様々なMacのオペレーションで有効ですので活用して下さい

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます。